# Pyspark conditional running window

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
starttime           |  endtime            |
2022-01-01 03:25:53 | 2022-01-01 03:25:52 |
2022-01-01 03:25:53 | 2022-01-01 03:25:52 |
2022-01-01 03:25:53 | 2022-01-01 03:25:52 |
2022-01-01 03:25:55 | 2022-01-01 03:25:54 |
2022-01-01 03:25:57 | 2022-01-01 03:25:57 |
```

I want to add another column which is a rownumber/rank which increments if difference between starttime and endtime is greater than 1 second.

So, the expected result should look something like this

```
starttime           |  endtime            | group |
2022-01-01 03:25:53 | 2022-01-01 03:25:52 | 1     |
2022-01-01 03:25:53 | 2022-01-01 03:25:52 | 1     |
2022-01-01 03:25:53 | 2022-01-01 03:25:52 | 1     |
2022-01-01 03:25:55 | 2022-01-01 03:25:54 | 2     |
2022-01-01 03:25:57 | 2022-01-01 03:25:57 | 3     |
```

Comment: Please tell more, which differences are you talking about? which specific values form a difference greater than 1 second - I see several of differences, so it's hard to interpret. Be as precise as possible.

Comment: Please start by showing what you've tried when asking a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand the entries will be ordered by starttime and when difference between starttime and next endtime is greater than second we need group +1.

So based on above requirement we can use lag and running sum to achieve the same

```
test=spark.createDataFrame([("2022-01-01 03:25:53","2022-01-01 03:25:52"),("2022-01-01 03:25:53","2022-01-01 03:25:52"),("2022-01-01 03:25:53","2022-01-01 03:25:52"),("2022-01-01 03:25:55","2022-01-01 03:25:54"),("2022-01-01 03:25:57","2022-01-01 03:25:57")],"starttime string,endtime string")

test.withColumn("starttime",to_timestamp("starttime")).withColumn("endtime",to_timestamp("starttime")).\
withColumn("diff",when(unix_timestamp("endtime")-unix_timestamp(lag("starttime",1).over(Window.orderBy("starttime")))>1,1).otherwise(0)).\
withColumn("group",1+sum("diff").over(Window.orderBy("starttime"))).\
drop("diff").show()

#output
+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|          starttime|            endtime|group|
+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|2022-01-01 03:25:53|2022-01-01 03:25:53|    1|
|2022-01-01 03:25:53|2022-01-01 03:25:53|    1|
|2022-01-01 03:25:53|2022-01-01 03:25:53|    1|
|2022-01-01 03:25:55|2022-01-01 03:25:55|    2|
|2022-01-01 03:25:57|2022-01-01 03:25:57|    3|
+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
```